# Watson Speech to text could not resolve host

Tags: curl, command-line, libcurl, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I'm trying to use the ibm watson speech to text service. Using Curl and the appropriate credentials i'm getting an error and don't understand why. I'm new to this so i need some help

I'm using this command-lines to get the text out of an audio file:

```
 curl -u username:password -X POST \ --header "Content-Type: audio/flac" \ --header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" \ --data-binary @/tmp/0001.flac \ "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true"
```

and i'm getting this error:

curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  --header
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Content-Type
curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  --header
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Transfer-Encoding
curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  --data-binary
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 
curl: (1) Protocol  https not supported or disabled in libcurl

does anybody know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: The `\ --header` escapes the space before `--header` so it's not recognized as an option.

Comment: i don't follow.. you're saying i should eliminate the \?

Comment: Indeed. It's possible that the original commandline was spanning multiple lines; in that case the `\ ` would mean to append the next line. But when it's not the last character in the line, it escapes the next character, changing the `--header` parameter to ` --header` (with an extra space). It doesn't start with `--` and is seen as the hostname rather than an option.

Comment: dude you're a life saver. it worked. i did it earlier but i guess i left an extra space or something. but now it worked. thanks!

Comment: Awesome ;-) You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `/` from the curl command, we use them in the [API Reference](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/#recognize) to better display the curl commands but they don't work in Windows.

```
curl -u username:password -X POST  
--header "Content-Type: audio/flac"  
--header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"
--data-binary @/tmp/0001.flac 
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true"
```

The command will work in unix based system like Ubuntu or Mac.